# Javascript Namespace - Multiple Levels

Tags: javascript, javascript-namespaces

I'm currently doing the following to give my javascript code a namespace:

```
(function(foo, $, undefined) {
    // function: showNoteDialog
    foo.showNoteDialog = function() {
       // ...
    }
}(window.foo = window.foo || {}, jQuery));
```

What I would prefer is instead of:

```
foo.showNoteDialog()
```

Is to have a multiple level namespace:

```
foo.notes.showDialog()
foo.other.showDialog()
```

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There aren't namespaces in JS, but you can assign objects to other objects like

```
x = {};
x.y = {};
x.y.z = function() {};
```

Comment: To be fair, these are commonly called "namespaces" in the JS community when they're used to organize code.

Comment: Sure. I'm just pointing out they're not real namespaces, they just look like them.

Answer (score 9):

Here is how i normally do it:

```
var TopLevel = TopLevel || {}; //Exentd or Create top level namespace
TopLevel.FirstChild = TopLevel.FirstChild || {}; //Extend or Create a nested name inside TopLevel
```

Using this method allows for safety between files. If TopLevel already exists you will assign it to the TopLevel variable, if it does not you will create an empty object which can be extended.

So assuming you want to create an application that exists within the Application namespace and is extended in multiple files you would want files that look like so:

**File 1 (library):**

```
var Application = Application || {};

Application.CoreFunctionality = Application.CoreFunctionality || {};
Application.CoreFunctionality.Function1 = function(){
  //this is a function
}//Function1
```

**File 2 (library):**

```
var Application = Application || {};

Application.OtherFunctionality = Application.OtherFunctionality || {};
Application.OtherFunctionality.Function1 = function(){
  //this is a function that will not conflict with the first
}
```

**File 3 (worker):**

```
//call the functions (note you could also check for their existence first here)
Application.CoreFunctionality.Function1();
Application.OtherFunctionality.Function1();
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [namespace.js](http://jweir.github.com/namespace/). It allows you to declare nested namespaces with public and private methods. It's nice because it allows you to call any method inside the namespace block without a prefix--regardless of scope.

```
(function() {
  namespace("example.foo", bar);

  function foobar() { return "foobar"; };
  function bar() { return foobar(); };
}());

example.foo.bar(); // -> "foobar"
```

Answer (score 1):

I do it using [bob.js framework](http://www.bobjs.com):

```
bob.ns.setNs('myApp.myMethods', {
    method1: function() {
        console.log('This is method 1');
    },

    method2: function() {
        console.log('This is method 2');
    }
});
//call method1.
myApp.myMethods.method1();
//call method2.
myApp.myMethods.method2();
```

Answer (score 1):

Automating multilevel namespaces declaration in javascript is very simple as you can see:

```
var namespace = function(str, root) {
    var chunks = str.split('.');
    if(!root)
        root = window;
    var current = root;
    for(var i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        if (!current.hasOwnProperty(chunks[i]))
            current[chunks[i]] = {};
        current = current[chunks[i]];
    }
    return current;
};

// ----- USAGE ------

namespace('ivar.util.array');

ivar.util.array.foo = 'bar';
alert(ivar.util.array.foo);

namespace('string', ivar.util);

ivar.util.string.foo = 'baz';
alert(ivar.util.string.foo);
```

Try it out: http://jsfiddle.net/stamat/Kb5xY/
Blog post: http://stamat.wordpress.com/2013/04/12/javascript-elegant-namespace-declaration/